# Magento 2 - Show error/success message as Alert/Modal

Tags: magento2, alert, success-message, notification, error-message

I want to show Magento all success/error message as alert or in a modal. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason for that? as if you keep showing success/error messages with modal, browsers will give the user option to block them. So after 2-3 modal, all of your modals on the site will be blocked if the user ask for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for showing a message as **Modal** to your `phtml` file

```
<button type="submit" id="gotoreviewform" class="action submit primary write-action"><span>Click to Open</span></button>
<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display: none;" >
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?php /* @noEscape */ echo __('Popup Modal Message!') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function($, modal){

var options = {
    type: 'popup',
    responsive: true,
    innerScroll: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
        class: '',
        click: function () {
            this.closeModal();
        }
    }]
};
var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#gotoreviewform").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#review-form").offset().top
        }, 1000);

    $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
});
});
</script>
```